# Is there a situation where DataSet is better than using EF?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, entity-framework-4, dataset

We are starting to develop web application for our client. Though I am not convinced, we are going to use DataSet as our data access. One of the reason is that most of the team members have experience using DataSet. It is my first time to experience DataSet. I am just curious if there is a situation that we choose DataSet than EF other than the reason mentioned.

Comment: `DataSet` is inconceivably clumsy when compared to LINQ. I can't imagine that people seriously consider using datasets as cornerstone of a DAL. It's a far-reaching decision. It determines the root of the architecture: data oriented vs object oriented. You know the saying "the stone age didn't end because they ran out of stones"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataSet would be the wrong choice and finally you will face with the bunch of the limits, including the architectual ones

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Merging large complex data object lists with multiple levels. Dynamic data. Disconnected change tracking. Adding fields on the fly. Avoiding reflection. There are ton of things that datasets are better at than object collections.

If Microsoft had ever made typed datasets with nullable types, it would have been a game changer and got rid of the massive clunk that is DBNull.Value which is my only major complaint.

And with Typed Datasets, Linq is fine